# Should we encourage new members to format their code?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Everyday we see loads of questions with poor (code!) formatting and MOST of them (but not all) are people who have reputation 1, probably new comers. (?)

Should we encourage them to format their code, or format them ourselves, or how to encourage them?

Comment: [Encourage. Wait. See edit. Comment. Fix. Hope for better. Comment. Sigh.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29322209/1026459)

Comment: YES ! ​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Sure. Also, we should also encourage them to include all (and only) proper tags. And have a clear question. In understandable English. With a proper description of the problem, and steps to reproduce (if applicable). Oh -- and on topic. Maybe we should tell them to read [the Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).